# JSX element 'body' has no corresponding closing tag

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I am creating a landing page on react.js. It is a page where users who aren't signed up have a page where they can signup for the website if they want to. However, I have some errors including one on the `<body>` tag where it says "JSX element 'body' has no corresponding closing tag." Can anyone help me solve this issue?

```
function Landing() {
    return (
        <body>
     <header>
        <div class="container">
          <h1 class="school-logo-text float-left">
            <a href="#"><strong>Direct</strong> Connection</a>
          </h1>
          <div class="site-header__menu group">
            <nav class="main-navigation">
              <ul>
                <li><a href="Events.html">Events</a></li>
                <li><a href="blog.html">Blog</a></li>
              </ul>
            </nav>
            <div class="site-header__util">
              <a href="login.html" class="btn btn--small btn--orange float-left push-right">Login</a>
              <form class="" action="front-page.html" method="post"></form>
              <input type="text" name="value" value="" placeholder="Search DC"></input>
              <input type="submit" name=""></input>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
   </header>

      <div class="page-banner">
        <div class="page-banner__bg-image" style="background-image: url(images/connection.jpg); height: 579px;
        width: 100%;"></div>
              <div class="page-banner__content container t-center c-white">
                <h1 class="headline headline--large">Direct Connection</h1>
                <a href="" class="btn btn--large btn--blue">Companies</a>
                          <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-10 col-md-offset-1-text-center white">
        
                  <h1>What DC has to offer</h1>
                      <p>DC is a company that makes connecting faster, easier and more convenient. We can help you and your company to get your personal
                         or business name out there. We are the first Online Company convention center. 
                        You will find yourself traveling through a variety of companies that you can interact with online. You
                        can locate a company and immediately request open bids on projects, connect with different departments through the company, send payment and receive payment, 
                        find the next date that company will be interacting and do live meetings and marketing via zoom, webinars, skype and much more. Think as if you just saved yourself hours on
                         end locating your next company project and add a few members to your team along the way.    
                        Find what request application forms and highly qualified employees  connected to Companies that Qualified employees,  future investors, employees
                          with  other swap company information swap, quotes send quotes, futuristic, billing processing. DC connections can help get companies` portfolios easily available.</p>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="full-width-split group">
                <div class="full-width-split__one">
                  <div class="full-width-split__inner">
                    <h2 class="headline headline--small-plus t-center">Upcoming Events</h2>
                    
          
                    <div class="event-summary">
                      <a class="event-summary__date t-center" href="#">
                        <span class="event-summary__month">Mar</span>
                        <span class="event-summary__day">25</span>
                      </a>
                      <div class="event-summary__content">
                        <h5 class="event-summary__title headline headline--tiny"><a href="#">Traffic Control Items</a></h5>
                        <p>We will have a discussion to discuss any traffic control items any company needs for improvement<a href="#" class="nu gray">Learn more</a></p>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="event-summary">
                      <a class="event-summary__date t-center" href="#">
                        <span class="event-summary__month">Apr</span>
                        <span class="event-summary__day">02</span>
                      </a>
                      <div class="event-summary__content">
                        <h5 class="event-summary__title headline headline--tiny"><a href="#">Chattanooga Traffic Plan</a></h5>
                        <p>In this event, we will discuss how we need to set up for lane closures. <a href="#" class="nu gray">Learn more</a></p>
                      </div>
                    </div>
          
                    <p class="t-center no-margin"><a href="#" class="btn btn--blue">View All Events</a></p>
                  </div>
                </div>

                <div class="full-width-split__two">
                  <div class="full-width-split__inner">
                    <h2 class="headline headline--small-plus t-center">From Our Blogs</h2>
                                <div class="event-summary">
                          <a class="event-summary__date event-summary__date--beige t-center" href="">
                            <span class="event-summary__month">Dec</span>
                            <span class="event-summary__day">29</span>  
                          </a>
                          <div class="event-summary__content">
                            <h5 class="event-summary__title headline headline--tiny"><a href="">Welcome Southern Company</a></h5>
                            <p>Southern Company has decided to join our community! <a href="" class="nu gray">Read more</a></p>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                       
            
                    
                    
                    
                    <p class="t-center no-margin"><a href="http://direct-connection.local/blog" class="btn btn--yellow">View All Blog Posts</a></p>
                  </div>
                </div>
                </div>
                <footer class="site-footer">
                  <div class="site-footer__inner container container--narrow">
                    <div class="group">
                      <div class="site-footer__col-one">
                        <h1 class="school-logo-text school-logo-text--alt-color">
                          <a href="index.html"><strong>Direct</strong> Connection</a>
                        </h1>
                        <p><a class="site-footer__link" href="index.html">706-263-0175</a></p>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
            </footer>
       </body>
    )
}

export default Landing
```

Comment: There's two `</div>` missing. `<div class="page-banner">` is unterminated, and some of its child divs. You'll need to close them at the appropriate spot. Consider trying `prettier` to format the code for you after you fix it - it's helpful for catching stuff like this.

Comment: as long as you're using react, you you may create a Layout using the Outlet function from react-router-dom
it's much better to separate your header, and footer out of body,
so try to create a separated files for header and footer and import them into the layout.js file
and define your lay out like this 
`export default const Layout = () => { return ( <> <Header /> <Outlet /> <Footer /> </> ) }`
then use you're layout at the app.js
then you'll use the header and footer on all pages and changing only body as the outlet will target each rout as the body ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pasting your html into the [w3c markup validator](https://validator.w3.org/nu/#textarea) shows a few errors. You've got two divs which are not closed, and you have `</input>` closing tags - which aren't a thing.

Have a look at the markup validator, it points out specifically what you've got wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You got the error because you missed two closing `<div>` tags.
It was an easy mistake due to the absence of good code formatting, as your file became long and deeply nested.

I will also advise refactoring and splitting into components to aid maintainability.
Also, `<input />` tags in HTML5 are self-closing tags. You need not write it like so: `<input></input>`.

Below is a formatted and fixed version of your code:

```
  return (
    <body>
      <header>
        <div class="container">
          <h1 class="school-logo-text float-left">
            <a href="#"><strong>Direct</strong> Connection</a>
          </h1>
          <div class="site-header__menu group">
            <nav class="main-navigation">
              <ul>
                <li><a href="Events.html">Events</a></li>
                <li><a href="blog.html">Blog</a></li>
              </ul>
            </nav>
            <div class="site-header__util">
              <a href="login.html" class="btn btn--small btn--orange float-left push-right">Login</a>
              <form class="" action="front-page.html" method="post"></form>
              <input type="text" name="value" value="" placeholder="Search DC"></input>
              <input type="submit" name=""></input>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </header>

      <div class="page-banner">
        <div class="page-banner__bg-image" style="background-image: url(images/connection.jpg); height: 579px;
        width: 100%;"></div>
        <div class="page-banner__content container t-center c-white">
          <h1 class="headline headline--large">Direct Connection</h1>
          <a href="" class="btn btn--large btn--blue">Companies</a>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-10 col-md-offset-1-text-center white">
              <h1>What DC has to offer</h1>
              <p>DC is a company that makes connecting faster, easier and more convenient. We can help you and your company to get your personal
                  or business name out there. We are the first Online Company convention center. 
                You will find yourself traveling through a variety of companies that you can interact with online. You
                can locate a company and immediately request open bids on projects, connect with different departments through the company, send payment and receive payment, 
                find the next date that company will be interacting and do live meetings and marketing via zoom, webinars, skype and much more. Think as if you just saved yourself hours on
                  end locating your next company project and add a few members to your team along the way.    
                Find what request application forms and highly qualified employees  connected to Companies that Qualified employees,  future investors, employees
                  with  other swap company information swap, quotes send quotes, futuristic, billing processing. DC connections can help get companies` portfolios easily available.
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="full-width-split group">
            <div class="full-width-split__one">
              <div class="full-width-split__inner">
                <h2 class="headline headline--small-plus t-center">Upcoming Events</h2>
                <div class="event-summary">
                  <a class="event-summary__date t-center" href="#">
                    <span class="event-summary__month">Mar</span>
                    <span class="event-summary__day">25</span>
                  </a>
                  <div class="event-summary__content">
                    <h5 class="event-summary__title headline headline--tiny"><a href="#">Traffic Control Items</a></h5>
                    <p>We will have a discussion to discuss any traffic control items any company needs for improvement<a href="#" class="nu gray">Learn more</a></p>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="event-summary">
                  <a class="event-summary__date t-center" href="#">
                    <span class="event-summary__month">Apr</span>
                    <span class="event-summary__day">02</span>
                  </a>
                  <div class="event-summary__content">
                    <h5 class="event-summary__title headline headline--tiny"><a href="#">Chattanooga Traffic Plan</a></h5>
                    <p>In this event, we will discuss how we need to set up for lane closures. <a href="#" class="nu gray">Learn more</a></p>
                  </div>
                </div>
          
                <p class="t-center no-margin"><a href="#" class="btn btn--blue">View All Events</a></p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="full-width-split__two">
              <div class="full-width-split__inner">
                <h2 class="headline headline--small-plus t-center">From Our Blogs</h2>
                <div class="event-summary">
                  <a class="event-summary__date event-summary__date--beige t-center" href="">
                    <span class="event-summary__month">Dec</span>
                    <span class="event-summary__day">29</span>  
                  </a>
                  <div class="event-summary__content">
                    <h5 class="event-summary__title headline headline--tiny"><a href="">Welcome Southern Company</a></h5>
                    <p>Southern Company has decided to join our community! <a href="" class="nu gray">Read more</a></p>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <p class="t-center no-margin"><a href="http://direct-connection.local/blog" class="btn btn--yellow">View All Blog Posts</a></p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <footer class="site-footer">
        <div class="site-footer__inner container container--narrow">
          <div class="group">
            <div class="site-footer__col-one">
              <h1 class="school-logo-text school-logo-text--alt-color">
                <a href="index.html"><strong>Direct</strong> Connection</a>
              </h1>
              <p><a class="site-footer__link" href="index.html">706-263-0175</a></p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </footer>
    </body>
  )
}

export default Landing
```